# toString() always returns empty Json object with proguard enabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, gson

My pro guard file is as follows

```html
# We only want obfuscation
-keepattributes InnerClasses,Signature

# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
#-optimizationpasses 5
#-allowaccessmodification

-libraryjars libs

-dontwarn bk.app.**
-keep class bk.app.com.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public interface com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
   }

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

# Serilaizable
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# APP DYNAMICS
-keep class com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.DontObfuscate
-keep @com.appdynamics.eumagent.runtime.DontObfuscate class * { *; }

# GOOGLE MAPS
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }

# TESTFAIRY
-keep class com.testfairy.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.testfairy.**

# Joda Time 2.3
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }

# OTTO RULES
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

# Butter knife
-keep @interface butterknife.*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @butterknife.On* <methods>;
}

-keep class **$$ViewInjector {
    public static void inject(...);
    public static void reset(...);
}

-keep class **$$ViewBinder {
    public static void bind(...);
    public static void unbind(...);
}

# VIEWPAGER
-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.**

# OKHTTP
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**

#GLIDE
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

# RETRO LAMBDA
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

# RETROFIT RULES
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {@retrofit.http.* <methods>;}
-keep interface retrofit.** { *;}
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**

-keep class com.google.gson.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class retrofit.* { *; }

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class bk.app.com.models.** { *; }
-keep class bk.app.com.models.** { <fields>; }

# keep enum so gson can deserialize it
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```

and the model is

```
import android.support.annotation.Keep;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.parceler.Parcel;

@Parcel @Keep
public class LoginRequest {

static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
String password;

public LoginRequest(){

}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The username
 */
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

/**
 *
 * @param username
 * The username
 */
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

/**
 *
 * @param password
 * The password
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
}
```

If I have minifyEnabled true in my gradle file I get the request to be an empty string like `{ }` when I call the toString() method of the class. I tried every possible solution but to no luck.

Comment: Did you find out why this happened?

Comment: No, still waiting for some one to provide feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it is not related to GSON. If you use proguard just keep in mind the proguard can remove some fields from class for example if the App doesn't use getters of class. So for fix this problem just add rule to your proguard config like:

```
# Classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
 -keep class com.myclass.data.model.** { *; }
```

Or easer to add annotation @Keep to your field like:

```
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
@Keep
String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
@Keep
String password;
```